# Iptables save expected behaviour

Tags: iptables, centos6

I was updating my iptables in CentOS 6.4

I added port 8080 to iptables and ran iptables save. However now when I view my iptables all it is showing me is:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Apr  9 13:46:25 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [135:9225]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [85:12488]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr  9 13:46:25 2014
```

Is this a summarised view or have I saved my iptables horribly wrong?

```
iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 177 packets, 14590 bytes)
  pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) 
  pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 135 packets, 22979 bytes) 
  pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination
```

Comment: What is the output for `iptables -L -n -v` ?

Comment: Not much: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 177 packets, 14590 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 135 packets, 22979 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: I have updated your question with this. Seems that your rules are not here...How did you setup them ? If you saved them with `iptables-save` try to restore them with `iptables-restore`

Comment: Used vi to edit the iptables and then :wq However I saw another user suggested using iptables save so I ran that. Now it is like this

Comment: So you have a script to manage your iptables rules ? well, run it

Comment: No script. I just went in and overwrote the current iptables with what was in the iptables.save file

Comment: Did you run `service iptables save` ?

Comment: Yes, after I inserted a new rule for allowing incoming connections to  port 8080

Comment: what was the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` after `service iptables store` did you run that as root?

Answer (score 1):

Using `iptables-save` without arguments will output all rules directly from the kernel. If it shows no rules, I would trust that you really do not have any rules. What command did you use to add a rule? What did you do after that, before running `iptables-save`?

Comment: Yes I used it without arguments. I used vi and inserted rules in the iptables file. Didn't do anything between than and iptables save (no dash)

Comment: Then you need to load that file; in it's simplest form: `iptables-restore < /path/to/file/you/edited`

Comment: So you did not even load the updated iptables file into the kernel? That would explain why the rule is not in the kernel. I think the command to load it like it happens during boot would be `service iptables start`, but it may be better to use `iptables-restore < filename` to load it. Remember that if you are doing this over a network connection, you could potentially kick yourself off the machine, so be careful.

Comment: I've always edited the file directly and saved in vi. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Red Hat Linux would load rules from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` at boot. The same probably applies to many of the distributions based on Red Hat Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The persistent iptable rules for CentOS6 is stored under `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. iptables-save will print out rules to STDOUT which is not what you want.

If you make changes to running iptables config and would like to make those persistent, then instead of running `iptables-save`, do

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: See my comment and the OPs reply - it looks like this is just what they did.

Comment: OK then it should just work, unless there were syntax errors in the iptables rule to add,or if the save command was run with insufficient perms.

Comment: It looks like the OP didn't have any rules loaded. They edited their /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, then ran service iptables save and overwrote their rules ::shurgs::

Comment: that would explain the observed behaviour.